# Create Code Snippet (easy to cut and paste) from Web Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like a staff of non-developers to be able to enter text into 4-5 fields in a form (date, time, price, description) then have a box at the bottom of the page that shows custom HTML code with their answers automatically embedded, so they can cut-and-paste the HTML.

Alternatively, send the form to a second page but display it as HTML source code HTML that they can Select All, Cut, then Paste into another app.

Thanks.

```
text [form field]

name: [bob]
price: [50]
description: [come to our event]
url for event: [url.com/event-02]

<html>
<p class="name">bob</p>
<p class="price">50</p>
<p class="desc">come to our event</p>
<p class="url">Share the <a href="url.com/event-02">event with your friends</a></p> 
</html>
```

This way they don't have to mess with HTML.

Comment: If you want someone to write code for you... hire them and pay them. Thanks.

Comment: You could do this with a spreadsheet and few functions.

Comment: Thanks Meni, and in the future I will be more specific (initially I just wanted a direction to go in, but Meni's solution works perfectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this, using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the input from the user:

*HTML:*

```
name:<input type="text" id="name" />
<br />
price:<input type="text" id="price"/>
<br />
description:<input type="text" id="description"/>
<br />
url for event:<input type="text" id="url_for_event" />
<br />
<button id="create-html">create html</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

*JS:*

```
$( "#create-html" ).click(function() {
    var name = '<p class="name">' + $("#name").val() + '</p>';
    var price = '<p class="price">' + $("#price").val() + '</p>';
    var description = '<p class="desc">' + $("#description").val() +'</p>';
    var url_for_event = '<p class="url">Share the <a href="' + $("#url_for_event").val() +'">event with your friends</a></p>';
    $( "#result" ).text(name + price + description + url_for_event);
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cLK7z/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Try making the submit button trigger a JS function.

```
<form action="">
  <!-- your form -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="parseThisCrapIntoHtml(this);return!1" />
</form>
```

Now, parsing into HTML should be relatively straightforward, mostly comprised of string manipulation.